# 'UserAgent.h' file not found flutter firebase iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I am working on flutter application with firebase, when i use the firebaseAuth plugin application give the following error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           131.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
2020-02-28 16:05:06.832 XCBBuildService[68423:382033] Failed to remove: 
/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner- hfqwisipukhnqobtbsvjhfltdbgs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/1be627f6c729f1a388e5fec96804d392-manifest.xcbuild: unlink(/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hfqwisipukhnqobtbsvjhfltdbgs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/1be627f6c729f1a388e5fec96804d392-manifest.xcbuild): No such file or directory (2)
2020-02-28 16:05:07.269 XCBBuildService[68423:382033] Failed to remove: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hfqwisipukhnqobtbsvjhfltdbgs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/1be627f6c729f1a388e5fec96804d392-desc.xcbuild: unlink(/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hfqwisipukhnqobtbsvjhfltdbgs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/1be627f6c729f1a388e5fec96804d392-desc.xcbuild): No such file or directory (2)
* BUILD FAILED *


Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/apple/Library/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.15.5+2/darwin/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:7:9: fatal error: 'UserAgent.h' file not found
#import "UserAgent.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

i am using these libraries-

```
firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+2
firebase_storage: ^3.1.1
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4
```

anyone have idea how to solve this error?, i have already done following things

```
flutter clean
deleted podfile.lock
deleted pods folder
pod deintegrate
pod repo update
pod install
```

but don't help me to solve this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We were struggling with the same error. It seems it's a firebase_auth dependency bug (firebase_core v0.4.4+2).

First, run `flutter clean`, then change your dependencies on pubspec.yaml to

```
dependencies: 
  firebase_auth: 0.15.4
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core: 0.4.4
```

Hope it helps!